# Using Generics with Script#

Tags: script#

I'm trying to refactor some of our Script# code to reduce duplicate code. I'm trying to use generics to accomplish this but Script# refuses to build when I add this code (the only message it gives me is 'Build failed'):

```
public abstract class PageManagerBase<TItem>
{
    public List<TItem> _items;
}
```

Does anyone know if there's a workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Script# supports generics for internal types only, so things like `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, or `List<T>`, but doesn't support custom types that you would create yourself.

So, you can use the ones that are already provided for you, but you can't create your own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think script# supports generics yet. check out the roadmap over here http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp